Group representation classification via Frobenius theorem
I am struggling to understand the following argument on the classification of irreducible representation as real, complex or quaternionic:

Let $G$ be a group and $V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $\rho: G\rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(V)$ is an irreducible representation.
By Schur's lemma,
$$
   End_{G}(V) := \{f: V\rightarrow V| f\text{ linear, }\forall g\in G: f\circ \rho(g) = \rho(g)\circ f\}
$$
is a division algebra. Hence by Frobenius theorem, $End_G(V)\cong \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{H}$.

Question: since $End_G(V)$ is an algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, how can we apply Frobenius theorem, which is a result about real division algebras?
My guess: we can consider the realification of $End_G(V)$ by restricting the scalars to $\mathbb{R}$, resulting in a real division algebra, to which Frobenius theorem applies. So the statement is really that the realification of $End_G(V)$ is $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{H}$.
But this cannot be how we define whether an irrep is real, complex or quaternionic: $End_G(V)$, viewed as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, always has even dimension, at least before choosing a real structure, so it cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.
